# PDO and PHP Transaction Not Inserting Data and No Error is Given

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have the oho and pdo code tat executes a transaction on two separate sql tables the code is provided below.

```
try{    
    echo " we begin transaction ";
    $dbh->beginTransaction();   
    $stmt2 = $dbh->prepare( "INSERT INTO `members`( `username`, `email`, `password`, `time_created`) 
                  VALUES (:username , :email , :password , NOW())");

    $stmt2->bindParam(':username', $username , PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt2->bindParam(':email', $email , PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt2->bindParam(':password', $password , PDO::PARAM_STR); 

    $stmt3 = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO `members_groups` (`member_id` , `group_id`) 
                           VALUES((SELECT MAX(member_id) FROM members) , 
                               (SELECT group_id FROM groups WHERE permission = 0 ))");

    if($stmt2->execute() && $stmt3->execute()){
        $dbh->commit(); 
        echo "registered successfully";             
    }
}
catch (Exception $e){
    $dbh->rollback();
    echo "an error has occurred".$e.getMessage();
}
```

But the code is executed , the data is not inserted into the table and no error is produced either.
But all parameters have been set.

Comment: `$e.getMessage();` should be `$e->getMessage();`

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) _while testing_ right after your opening PHP tag for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` to see if it yields anything. This should have identified this simple compile error

Comment: Have you set PDO error mode attribute to exception?

Comment: Also take a look at [`->lastInsertId()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php) instead of having to do 2 SELECT's on the second query

Comment: Also PDO generates a `PDOException`